# How to get the child collection from the parent class mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have the follwoing model:

```
class User(Document):
    first_name = StringField(required=True)
    last_name = StringField(required=True)
    username = StringField(required=True)

class TwitterUser(User):
    meta = {"collection":"TwitterUsers"}
    access_token = StringField(required=True)
    twitter_id = StringField(required=True)

class FacebookUser(User):
    meta = {"collection":"FacebookUsers"}
    fb_id = StringField(required=True)
    access_token = StringField(required=True)
```

At some point in my application I need to retrieve a user based on the access_token. However If I have a Twitter user for instance and I do User.objects(access_token=at).get() I don't get a result. If I do TwitterUser.objects(access_token=cookie).get() it works.

Is there a way to get the child class by quering the parent collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is currently not possible - as `User` doesn't know its children have moved home and live in another collection.  Are you sure different collections are needed for the children?  If so you'd have to do multiple queries and stop once the `User` has been found.

Alternatively, you may want to change the schema and abstract out the common parts for querying and then have the Social platform specific parts in a different collection but linked via a `GenericReferenceField` - that would mean you'd always have 2 queries.